# Namespace use causes multiple definition of

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

I'm trying to make use of namespace but I'm getting a compilation error:

```
multiple definition of `B::Class1::Class1()
```

The following outlines the code structure I have here:

```
//.pro
SOURCES += ../main.cpp \
           ../a/class1.cpp \
           ../b/class1.cpp    
HEADERS += \
           ../a/class1.h \
           ../b/class1.h

// folder a, header
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H

namespace A {
class Class1 {
public:
    Class1();
};
}    
#endif // CLASS1_H

// folder a, source
#include "class1.h"    
using namespace A;

Class1::Class1() {
}

// folder b, header
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H

namespace B {
class Class1 {
public:
    Class1();
    void doB();
};
}    
#endif // CLASS1_H

// folder b, source
#include "class1.h"    
using namespace B;

Class1::Class1() {
}
void B::Class1::doB() {    
}

// main.cpp
#include "a/class1.h"
using namespace A;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Class1 c;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Here is the compilation output:

```
14:39:54: Running steps for project test...
14:39:54: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" clean
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug clean
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release clean
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/User/Downloads/namespace/build'
Makefile.Debug:133: warning: overriding recipe for target 'debug/class1.o'
Makefile.Debug:130: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'debug/class1.o'
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/User/Downloads/namespace/build'
Makefile.Release:133: warning: overriding recipe for target 'release/class1.o'
Makefile.Release:130: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'release/class1.o'
del debug\main.o debug\class1.o debug\class1.o
del release\main.o release\class1.o release\class1.o
Nao foi poss¡vel encontrar C:\Users\User\Downloads\namespace\build\release\main.o
Nao foi poss¡vel encontrar C:\Users\User\Downloads\namespace\build\debug\main.o
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/User/Downloads/namespace/build'
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/User/Downloads/namespace/build'
14:39:55: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
14:39:55: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
14:39:55: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/User/Downloads/namespace/build'
Makefile.Debug:133: warning: overriding recipe for target 'debug/class1.o'
Makefile.Debug:130: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'debug/class1.o'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -std=c++1y -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I. -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o ..\main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -std=c++1y -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I. -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\class1.o ..\b\class1.cpp
..\main.cpp:5:5: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     ^
..\main.cpp:5:5: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o debug\test.exe debug/main.o debug/class1.o debug/class1.o  -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -LC:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/mingw482_32/lib -lqtmaind -LC:\mingw482\mingw32\lib -LC:\Utils\icu32_52_1_mingw482\lib -LC:\utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib -LC:\utils\mysql\mysql\lib -LC:\opensll\lib -LC:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32/lib -lQt5Widgetsd -lQt5Guid -lQt5Cored 
debug/class1.o: In function `ZN1B6Class1C2Ev':
C:\Users\User\Downloads\namespace\build/../b/class1.cpp:4: multiple definition of `B::Class1::Class1()'
debug/class1.o:C:\Users\User\Downloads\namespace\build/../b/class1.cpp:4: first defined here
debug/class1.o: In function `ZN1B6Class1C2Ev':
C:\Users\User\Downloads\namespace\build/../b/class1.cpp:4: multiple definition of `B::Class1::Class1()'
debug/class1.o:C:\Users\User\Downloads\namespace\build/../b/class1.cpp:4: first defined here
debug/class1.o: In function `ZN1B6Class13doBEv':
C:\Users\User\Downloads\namespace\build/../b/class1.cpp:7: multiple definition of `B::Class1::doB()'
debug/class1.o:C:\Users\User\Downloads\namespace\build/../b/class1.cpp:7: first defined here
debug/main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\User\Downloads\namespace\build/../main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `A::Class1::Class1()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Debug:81: recipe for target 'debug\test.exe' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/User/Downloads/namespace/build'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\test.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
14:39:55: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
14:39:55: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Comment: What commands does `qmake` print?

Comment: How do you expect to distinguish between two includes of headers with the same name? Also the include guards are the same. But these issues should not cause the error you're showing.

Comment: Ok, got it. Namespaces allow me to select a particular scope from a set of scopes. To introduce these scopes I put them in different files (different file names). I have to use namespaces if these scopes contain symbols with the same name.

Comment: I still don't get why you want the files to have the right names. I consider that a design issue, problematic in general and will most probably explode. You have two namespaces, just name the files `a_class1.h` and `b_class1.h` (similarly for the .cpp). If you need to select one or the other you can wrap the `#include` within `#ifdef` or otherwise control it through the build system. Also I would avoid using directives....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like qmake doesn't support files with the same name in different directories.  It ends up trying to build both a/class1.cpp and b/class1.cpp into the same debug/class1.o file, and then link that file twice.

Try renaming one of your *.cpp files.

Comment: Well, that's the point. I was trying to understand how to use namespaces to be able to have "files with the same name in different directories". So, the issue here is more of `qmake` than of C++, may I say that?

Comment: @KcFnMi Who told you that namespaces and filenames are related at all? It's a `qmake` deficiency, you can't bypass it by doing anything other than: 1. changing the file name(s), or 2. modifying qmake itself, and certainly not by modifying the file contents!

Comment: I listen some people talk about cmake, is it an alternative to qmake (is this case)?